# When does firefox take website screen shot for its home page?

Tags: firefox, screenshot

When ever I earn a reputation, firefox understand and refresh my thumbnail. I want to know how it works and when does firefox take website screenshot for its home page?

Is there any `meta` tag or something like this to force firefox to take screenshot?

[image: My HomePage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you earn reputation firefox has no idea.  The javascript code (that stackoverflow loaded into firefox when you loaded the page) does.  If you don't have the page loaded and the javascript code running nothing will ever see the change.  Look up AJAX if you want to know more.

You can force the images to update but it involves loading the page.

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thumbnails-on-new-tab-page-are-missing?esab=a&s=new+tab+thumbnails&r=1&as=s

> **Make Firefox create new images for the new tab page**
>
> The images will get re-stored as you use the new tab page to go to
>   those websites again.
>
> - Open the new tab page by clicking the `+` button on the tab strip.
> - Click on one of the blank images to go to a website. Note, that it works only for left-click, opening in new tab doesn't do the trick.
> - This is important - let the website finish loading (wait for the spinning green loading icon in the tab to stop).
> - Open the new tab page again and you will see a new image for the website you just went to.
> - Repeat this process for the rest of the missing images.

Comment: For some reason all my site tabs are the initial login screens of the sites, not the content themselves.

Comment: Sounds like an old unfixed bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=949655